# Javascript: split by this|that

Tags: javascript, split

How can I split a string like this

```
var str = "M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0 z M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0 Z";

var arr4String = str.split('z|Z');
```

I'm expecting to get an array with 3 elements:

```
["M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0", "M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0", ""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex.  Using the `g` flag says search the entire string from beginning to end so that it doesn't stop the first time it hits a `z|Z`.  The `i` flag makes the search case-insensitive.

```
  var str = "M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0 z M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0 Z";

  var arr4String = str.split(/z/gi);
```

Comment: This looks solid and works for me. I will check this one :)

Comment: You do not need `/g` - it is the default behavior with `split`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split on a regular expression you need to pass a regular expression to `split` as a parameter:

```
var str = "M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0 z M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0 Z";

var arr4String = str.split(/z|Z/);
                           ^   ^
```

Produces:

```
["M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0 ", " M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0 ", ""]
                             ^    ^                         ^
```

(note the extra spaces, because the regex doesn't remove these).

If you'd like to trim the results you can either use:

```
...split(/\s*z\s*/i);
```

or you can simply chain with:

```
...split(/z/i).map(function (val) {
    return val.trim();
});
```

Comment: The output you will get is not what OP wants.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it works perfectly fine, OP just missed the spaces. If you want to remove spaces *as well* as split, then just use a `map` and `trim` call.

Comment: It can be done more gracefully with a regex. OP did not forget spaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, sure, it can be done simply, but the trick is to not oversimplify. It's really easy to attempt to do too much with regex and get in a bind when things start breaking, when most of the time a couple simple function calls will achieve the same result and make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can use the `/\s*z\s*/i` regex for splitting:

```js
var str = "M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0 z M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0 Z";
var arr4String = str.split(/\s*z\s*/i);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr4String,0,4) + "</pre>";
```

The `/\s*z\s*/i` regex will match zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`) before and after `z` (case-insensitive search is performed due to the `/i` modifier).

Comment: This feels a bit overpowered for my need. The `str.split(/z/gi)` would do, but thank you for your prompt response as well as the explain.

Comment: You do not need `/g` - it is the default behavior with `split`.

Comment: That's even more cute :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr4String = str.replace('z','Z').split('Z');
```

Comment: This looks nice as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you want a Regular Expression instead of a string which you can do by using a forward slash instead of a quotes (`/z|Z/`).

However, just using that won't get you what you want. You actually want a regular expression that removes surrounding whitespace around your "z" characters. Additionally, let's assume if you pass in a string that contains `"L100z200"` you wouldn't want that to split in the middle either. To accomplish that you can then use the `\b` to ensure there's a word boundry. Here you go:

```
var str = "M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0 z M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0 Z";

var arr4String = str.split(/\b\s*z\s*\b/i);
console.log(arr4String);
// Exactly:
// ["M50 0 L0 100 L100 100 L50 0", "M0 0 L100 0 L50  100 L0 0", ""]
```

Comment: Thank you but I feel that regex is a bit too much.

Comment: @thednp That's fine, but you are leaving yourself open for bugs and not getting exactly what you asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness (could be faster than /z/i):

```
var arr4String = str.split(/[zZ]/);
```